# Is there any way to save a webpage as a pdf document in flutter web view

Tags: pdf, flutter-web

I am currently using flutter `InAppWebView` Plugin.  I want to save a web page as a pdf file when the url of the page is given. I have used the `printCurrentPage()` method of the `InAppWebView` plugin but it does not return the filepath back to the app after saving the file so that it can be shown in a list view in the app itself. Can anyone help me save the webpage as a pdf and show the saved files as a list view.

I have tried `webcontent_converter` plugin too but it looses some content of the page like images and icon to include in the pdf file.